# How can I clear all my existing notifications in Trello?

Tags: trello

When I first started using Trello, I subscribed to the "Trello Resources" board. Whenever I click the "Notifications" button in Trello, I get a bunch of Resources notifications. I think I unsubscribed from the notifications in "Board Options" and "List Options", but the "Trello Resources" notifications still flood my notifications. What I can I do to fully unsubscribe from that board?

EDIT: I realized I'm not subscribe anymore, but all of the notifications are still present. How can I clear those? They're irrelevant and a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I'll keep it simple. As of now, there is no option to do what you would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Android App has a Clear All Notifications link that you can use.  I am sure other apps allow the same thing.  This is also easier than using the desktop browser version which wants you to view notifications before it clears them.

Answer (score 0):

On the web app, you just go ahead and click on `notifications->view all notifications`, and when you go back to your Trello home page, all the notifications should be cleared.

Comment: This no longer seems to work. The only way I can seem to clear notifications from the web app now is by clicking on them one-by-one.